# Cassandra >= 3.0 on Travis-ci?

Tags: cassandra, travis-ci, cassandra-3.0

Does anyone have a successful formula for running Cassandra 3.x (any version will do at this point) on Travis-ci.org? I tried these instructions here:

https://www.codinglogs.com/using-travis-ci-with-cassandra-3-x/

And any number of variations, but all I ever get is:

```
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have pretty much followed the blog; slightly deviated on wget part alone.
instead of
    `wget http://www.us.apache.org/dist/cassandra/3.3/apache-cassandra-3.3-bin.tar.gz && tar -xvzf apache-cassandra-3.3-bin.tar.gz`

I used

```
wget http://www.us.apache.org/dist/cassandra/3.9/apache-cassandra-3.9-bin.tar.gz && tar -xvzf apache-cassandra-3.9-bin.tar.gz
```

here is my [travis.yml](https://github.com/harrydevnull/cdrs/blob/master/.travis.yml)

```
addons:  
  apt:
   packages:
    - oracle-java8-installer

before_install:    
  - sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
  - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
  - java -version
  - sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/*
  - wget http://www.us.apache.org/dist/cassandra/3.9/apache-cassandra-3.9-bin.tar.gz && tar -xvzf apache-cassandra-3.9-bin.tar.gz
  - sudo sh ./apache-cassandra-3.3/bin/cassandra -R
  - sleep 20
```

Comment: Thanks for this. There must be something else in my travis build that is interfering with this recipe. I've got to get back to this at some point...